# mysql syntax error when altering table

Tags: mysql, sql, alter-table

I have a syntax error when adding a new column to a table. Every other column is added correct apart from this:

```
ALTER TABLE stock.stock_data ADD LEGAL_&_GENERAL VARCHAR(40);
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Remove the `&`.  Use `and`.

Comment: Don't use `&` in you table name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MySQL (as with all databases) limits the characters in unquoted identifiers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html):

> Permitted characters in unquoted identifiers:
>
> ASCII: [0-9,a-z,A-Z$_] (basic Latin letters, digits 0-9, dollar,
>   underscore)
>
> Extended: U+0080 .. U+FFFF

Note that "&" is not one of them.  The preferred way to fix this is to use "normal" characters:

```
ALTER TABLE stock.stock_data ADD LEGAL_AND_GENERAL VARCHAR(40);
```

If you really want to, you can quote the identifier:

```
 ALTER TABLE stock.stock_data ADD `LEGAL_&_GENERAL` VARCHAR(40);
```

However, you will have to quote the name wherever you use the column, just cluttering your queries and wearing out the back-tick key.

Answer (score 1):

Use ` to escape &

```
ALTER TABLE stock.stock_data ADD `LEGAL_&_GENERAL` VARCHAR(40);
```

See [Identifier Qualifiers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/identifier-qualifiers.html)